# How can I view multiple inflight toolbar windows at the same time?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

During flight, there is a toolbar on the right with icons. Hovering or clicking an icon shows a little window with helpful info like

- Current missions
- Current fuels/battery
- Various other windows (screenshots below) ...

You can click an icon to keep its window visible ... but it is still hidden when mousing over other windows.

Is there a way to "pin" more than one of these windows at once, and move them around the screen?

I'm open to solutions using popular/maintained mods.

[image]

Comment: Can you detail "various other windows"?

Comment: @Goufalite Yep, done.

Answer (score 1):

> Current missions

[CapCom mod](https://forum.kerbalspaceprogram.com/index.php?/topic/107789-18x-capcom-mission-control-on-the-go-v211-11-1-2019/)

> Current fuels/battery

I've never tracked fuel as independant resources, the main fuel data is  just deltaV. You can track it in the staging view, or else [Kerbal Engineer Redux](https://forum.kerbalspaceprogram.com/index.php?/topic/17833-130-kerbal-engineer-redux-1130-2017-05-28/) can help you put some elements in the HUD (for example RCS dV). EDIT: I don't have the answer after your clarification...

EDIT after clarification

> Alarm Clock

[Use the mod instead](https://forum.kerbalspaceprogram.com/index.php?/topic/22809-112x-kerbal-alarm-clock-v31300-april-10/), it's better, more precise on transfer windows, has more features and has a floating window.

> Messages

I don't think you need a floating window for this since the info doesn't pop very often, but I don't know on my side

> Action groups

I don't remember the names but there are some action group managers mods out there

> DeltaV

There are just UI switches, all the info is in the staging stack

Comment: The fuel window is useful e.g. in spaceplanes with air-breathing and non-air-breathing engines on the same stage (or just Rapiers, which act as both), since it tells you how much excess liquid fuel you have relative to oxidizer. (If you switch from jet to rocket mode too soon, you end up hauling excess LF to orbit; if you switch too late, you end up with excess oxidizer instead.) It's also useful for monitoring your battery status e.g. on ion-powered craft or when doing ISRU or transmitting science data, or just making sure you didn't forget to turn on auto-hibernate on your probe cores.